# Как реализовать скрол до элемента, который вышел за экран в RecyclerView

Tags: kotlin

У меня есть код:

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

вот так выглядит экран
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии на элемент он может выйти за экран. Как сделать так, чтобы до этого элемента можно было скролить?(элемент может выйти вниз за экран и вправо  )